# How to Assign a keyboard shortcut to a different combination?

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, copy, paste, cut-command

I have an issue where my copy and paste keyboard shortcuts are assigned to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>. Now that I am too used to using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, I would like to import the copy and paste functions that <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd> offers now. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> is doing the job of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>x</kbd> now.

How can I copy these three functions into <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd> ?
Thanks.

PS : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd>/<kbd>X</kbd> does nothing at all now!

Comment: And where does ctr+c/ctrl+v not work for you? In some certain application? Those are default copy/paste shortcuts all over the Linux desktops, as far as i  have experienced

Comment: It works nowhere @wk. . They are idle key combinations for me now.

Comment: Idea: some laptops have swapped `Ctrl` and `Fn` keys. Maybe you have such issue?

Comment: No. Mine laptop is not new. Ctrl C/V used to work before.

Comment: But all other Ctr-shortcuts are working? You give so few background, so it is too hard to imagine, where the problem may be. What happened before they stopped working?

Comment: CTRL A is working fine. I was in 14.04 till yesterday. Sometime while I was in 14.04 I lost they shortcuts. Must be a couple of months now. I honestly do not know what caused the issue.